# Google Chrome HTML <select> element doesn't select work Google Chrome mobile view

Tags: angularjs, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

my code is

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="picFile[$index].paperSize"  >
                                <option value="A4">A4</option>
                                <option value="A5">A5</option>
                                <option value="A3">A3</option>
                           </select>
```

this code working on other browser's mobile views.but it's doesn't  work on google chrome mobile view.

please help this question.

Comment: Might Google Chrome Remote Debugging helps you https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but I had same issue with Chrome on Android, and this jQuery has done the trick:

```
$('select').change(function(){
  if (/Android/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    $(this).blur();
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.